# What are the fallback url options in different environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I'm not setting ActionController default_url_options anywhere. I'm only setting ActionMailer default_url_options.

In development, my url generators use the correct protocol, domain name, and port (http://foo:8080).

In production, the url generators fall back to www.example.com. So what's correctly generated at http://foo::8080/things/123 in development is generated as http://www.example.com/things/123 in production.

How is rails guessing the correct domain in development but not in production?

Comment: Rails works with paths rather than with complete URLS. (/things/123 vs. http://foo::8080/things/123)

Comment: rails has both path and url generators. `thing_path(@thing)` and `thing_url(@thing)`

Comment: Yes, if you use thing_url it will include the domain and all.